# How to overwrite a web.config file with custom content in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, web-config, web-config-transform

I'm trying to extend my `web.config` file with custom server configuration that is necessary for IIS. But I'm not sure how to do this as there is already a `web.config` file auto-generated at publish time. So I need to merge my custom config into this file.

I already tried [to transform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/transform-webconfig) the `web.config` file but it just could not get it working. Even if it did I would have to create for example a `web.Debug.config` and `web.Release.config` with the same content.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error we found out that the solution is really easy (but for some reason we have not found a single helpful internet source that told us this thing):

**The `web.config` files just get merged at publish time!**

So I just:

1. Added a custom `web.config` file
2. with `Build Action: Content` and `Copy to Output Directory: Copy if newer` to be able to use the custom config at debug time

And now on publish I get a single `web.config` with both the auto generated and custom settings.